# mysql changing column to row heading

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that holds data like

```
   key        val
    Product    Oranges
    Customer   Alan Sherry
    Product    Apples
    Area       Isles
    Customer   John C
```

etc

and I want to change it to more like

```
Product     customer      Area
Oranges     Alan Sherry   Isles
Appleas     John C
```

how would I do that

thanks

Comment: How will you ensure that Alan Sherry appears in the same 'row' as Oranges? There doesn't seem to be any relationship between the various values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be hard to do using purely sql. You could use a cursor and look for product, customer, area (in a specific order, maybe?) and set variables for those 3 items until you come to product each time, then you flush the variables you've set into one row in the new table you've created using and insert statement and start reading again.

The statements inside the cursor will depend on the specifics on the data in the key val table.

Comment: I agree. This is not too hard to do in PHP for example, but purely in mysql...You can't do it in a single query, that's for sure. If he only has a limited range of 'key types', he can make another table and move it per type.